# Calculate only the working days in the last month to today's date (DAX)

Tags: dax

I figured out how to mark the weekdays, but the last month has only so many days used in the month. I need to make this code go to only today's date. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Note: This DAX code calculates all the working days in each month, but doesn't account for the last month in which days you have only used (to todays date).

```
   [CODE]
   WeekDaysCaseDateTimeCol = 
   SUMX(
   SELECTCOLUMNS(
    CALENDAR(FIRSTDATE('TableName'[DateTimeCol.[Date]), LASTDATE('TableName'[DateTimeCol].[Date])),
    "Date", MAX('TableName'[DateTimeCol].[Date]),
    "BUsinessDay", IF(WEEKDAY([Date],3) < 5, 1, 0)
),
[BusinessDay]
)
  [/CODE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

Filter in Kusto: | where WeekDaysCreateDateTimeCol == 1

Or you can filter in Power BI: Is greater than or equal to 1

And WeekDaysCreateDateTimeCol is not Blank